# printing out values from a key/value pairs object sequentially

Tags: javascript

I have a map of keys one, two and three with the values 3, 2 and 1.

how do I loop through them to get the output ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one']?

here's what I've tried so far and it's only looping through once

```js
const map = {
  'one': 3,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 1
}

// expected output
// ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one'];
let arr = [];

// while all values > 0

for (let key of Object.keys(map)) {
  if (map[key] > 0) {
    arr.push(key);
    map[key]--;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: does `for (let key in map)` work for you? converting to an array locks in the members of map that will be iterated...

Comment: is your expected output correct ?

Comment: you are just looping one time. You need to loop through your object until each key has a value of `0`

Answer (score 2):

Just add another loop around it:

```
  let keyLeft;
  do {
    keyLeft = false;
    for (let key of Object.keys(map)) {
       if (map[key] > 0) {
         arr.push(key);
         map[key]--;
         keyLeft = true;
       }
    }
  } while(keyLeft)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will set a flag that indicates if we have to keep looping again or not, like this:

```js
const map = {
  'one': 3,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 1
}

// expected output
// ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one'];
let arr = [];

// while all values > 0
let keepLooping = true;

while (keepLooping)
{
    keepLooping = false;

    for (let key of Object.keys(map))
    {
       if (map[key] > 0)
       {
           arr.push(key);
           map[key]--;
           keepLooping = true;
       }
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```